# How do I design a data structure having push() and popMin()operations with push() in O(log(n)) and popMin in constant time, i.e. O(1)?

Tags: data-structures

My own answer is binary search tree with next pointer， like this：

```c
 struct Node{
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* next; 
    Node* parent;
};
typedef struct Node MyNode;
MyNode* myTable;
MyNode* leftNode;
```

am I right, or is there some other answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Heap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

> insertion is O(logN)
>
> find-min is O(1)

Comment: thx, but I do not just find-min, I want find and delete min which is 'popMin'。